# How to omit NA values while pasting numerous column values together?

Tags: r, na

I have a data frame `dd2` with hundreds of columns and what I need to do is paste all these column values together omitting any `NA` values. If I do something like this

```
apply(dd2, 1, paste, collapse=",")
```

it actually includes `NA`s as `"NA"` string. I want to avoid that. I could also do as shown below, but this would expect me to work for each individual column at a time to get the result.

```
result <- cbind(    
    dd2, 
    combination = paste(dd2[,2], replace(dd2[,3], is.na(dd2[,3]), ""), sep = ",")
)
```

Is there any efficient way to do it? Here is the sample data:

```
dd2 <- structure(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "AK2", "HFM1", NA, "TRR", 
"RTT", NA, "PPT", "TRR", "RTT", NA, "PPT", NA, NA, "GGT", NA), .Dim = c(5L, 
4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("sample_id", "plant", "animal", 
"more")))
```

Comment: Your sample data is not a `data.frame`. With "dd2", are you just trying to paste together all of the columns except the first?

Comment: @AnandaMahto I want to paste select column values together omitting any NAs. For example, I want to paste `dd2[,wanted.columns]` .

Comment: Maybe something like this would work too: `melt(as.data.table(dd2), measure.vars = c("plant", "animal"), na.rm = TRUE)[, toString(value), by = .(sample_id, more)]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try `na.omit()` to omit the values, then paste.  Also, you could use `toString()`, as it is the equivalent of `paste(..., collapse = ", ")`.

```
apply(dd2, 1, function(x) toString(na.omit(x)))
# [1] "A, AK2, PPT"      "B, HFM1, PPT"     "C, TRR"          
# [4] "D, TRR, RTT, GGT" "E, RTT"
```

If you have specific columns you are using then

```
apply(dd2[, cols], 1, function(x) toString(na.omit(x)))
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify a different separator? (ex. "" instead of ,)?

Comment: @godines - not in `toString`.  You would have to use `paste`.

Comment: Thank you @RichScriven. The problem with `paste` is the `NA` cells. I could use `na.omit` as well, but then I get problems with the different number of rows. It should have an option to just ignore the `NA` cells.

Comment: `stringr::str_replace_na(c(NA, "abc", "def"), replacement='')`. Generally, refer to `stringr` for anything more advanced than simple concatenations.

Comment: @Ufos - Okay, but there is a little more to it than that.  `stringr::str_replace_na(dd2, replacement='')` does not produce the desired result.  Base R's `replace` could be used to do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

`dd2` is a matrix in which case using `apply` as suggested by @Rich Scriven is more appropriate. If it is a dataframe you can use `tidyr::unite`

```
dd2 <- data.frame(dd2)
tidyr::unite(dd2, result, plant, animal, more, na.rm = TRUE, sep = ',')

#  sample_id      result
#1         A     AK2,PPT
#2         B    HFM1,PPT
#3         C         TRR
#4         D TRR,RTT,GGT
#5         E         RTT
```

To combine all the columns you can use `everything()`.

```
tidyr::unite(dd2, result, dplyr::everything(), na.rm = TRUE, sep = ',')

#         result
#1     A,AK2,PPT
#2    B,HFM1,PPT
#3         C,TRR
#4 D,TRR,RTT,GGT
#5         E,RTT
```