# Create a new column in dplyr by appending values to a list from other columns?

Tags: r, list, if-statement, dplyr, case-when

I would like to make a new column by appending to a list conditional on the values of other columns. If possible, I would like to do so in `dplyr`. Sample input and desired output is below.

Suppose a dataframe `newdata`:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
dog  cat  NA   NA
NA   cat  foo  bar
dog  NA   NA   NA
NA   cat  NA   NA
```

Here is my desired output, with the new column `newCol`:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 newCol
dog  cat  NA   NA   (dog, cat)
NA   cat  foo  bar  (cat, foo, bar)
dog  NA   NA   NA   (dog)
NA   cat  NA   bar  (cat, bar)
```

I have tried using `ifelse` within `mutate` and `case_when` within `mutate`, but both will not allow concatenation to a list. Here is my (unsuccessful) attempt with `case_when`:

```
newdata = newdata %>% mutate( 
    newCol = case_when(
        col1 == "dog" ~ c("dog"),
        col2 == "cat" ~ c(newCol, "cat"),
        col3 == "foo" ~ c(newCol, "foo"),
        col4 == "bar" ~ c(newcol, "dog")
        )
    )
```

I tried a similar approach with an `ifelse` statement for each column but also could not append to the list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to omit NA values while pasting numerous column values together in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34428924/how-to-omit-na-values-while-pasting-numerous-column-values-together-in-r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Note at the end we show the input data used here. It is as in the question except we have added a row of NAs at the end to show that all solutions work in that case too.

We show both list and character column solutions. The question specifically refers to list so this is the assumed desired output but if it was intended that `newCol` be a character vector then we show that as well.

This is so easy to do using base functions that we show that first; however, we do redo it in tidyverse although it involves significantly more code.

**1) base** We can use `apply` like this:

```
reduce <- function(x) unname(x[!is.na(x)])
DF$newCol <- apply(DF, 1, reduce)
```

giving the following where `newCol` is a list whose first component is `c("dog", "cat")`, etc.

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4        newCol
1  dog  cat <NA> <NA>      dog, cat
2 <NA>  cat  foo  bar cat, foo, bar
3  dog <NA> <NA> <NA>           dog
4 <NA>  cat <NA> <NA>           cat
5 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

The last line of code could alternately be:

```
DF$newCol <- lapply(split(DF, 1:nrow(DF)), reduce)
```

The question refers to concatenating to a list so I assume that a list is wanted for `newCol` but if a string is wanted then use this for reduce instead:

```
reduce_ch <- function(x) sprintf("(%s)", toString(x[!is.na(x)]))
apply(DF, 1, reduce_ch)
```

**2) tidyverse** or using tpldyr/tidyr/tibble we gather it to long form, remove the NAs, nest it, sort it back to the original order and cbind it back with `DF`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)

DF %>%
   rownames_to_column %>%
   gather(colName, Value, -rowname) %>%
   na.omit %>%
   select(-colName) %>%
   nest(Value, .key = newCol) %>%
   arrange(rowname) %>%
   left_join(cbind(DF %>% rownames_to_column), .) %>% 
   select(-rowname)
```

giving:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4        newCol
1  dog  cat <NA> <NA>      dog, cat
2 <NA>  cat  foo  bar cat, foo, bar
3  dog <NA> <NA> <NA>           dog
4 <NA>  cat <NA> <NA>           cat
5 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>          NULL
```

If character output is wanted then use this instead:

```
DF %>%
   rownames_to_column %>%
   gather(colName, Value, -rowname) %>%
   select(-colName) %>%
   group_by(rowname) %>%
   summarize(newCol = sprintf("(%s)", toString(na.omit(Value)))) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   { cbind(DF, .) } %>%
   select(-rowname)
```

giving:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4          newCol
1  dog  cat <NA> <NA>      (dog, cat)
2 <NA>  cat  foo  bar (cat, foo, bar)
3  dog <NA> <NA> <NA>           (dog)
4 <NA>  cat <NA> <NA>           (cat)
5 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>              ()
```

### Note

The input `DF` in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "col1 col2 col3 col4
dog  cat  NA   NA
NA   cat  foo  bar
dog  NA   NA   NA
NA   cat  NA   NA
NA   NA   NA   NA"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines,  header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Solution using `na.omit()` and `paste()` with `collapse` argument:

```
apply(newdata, 1, 
      function(x) paste0("(", paste(na.omit(x), collapse = ", "), ")"))
[1] "(dog, cat)" "(cat, foo, bar)" "(dog)" "(cat)"
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a use case for `tidyr::unite`. You'll still need to do some dplyr cleanup at the end, but this should work for now.

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- tribble(~col1, ~col2, ~col3, ~col4,
              "dog", "cat", NA, NA,
              NA, "cat", "foo", "bar",
              "dog", NA, NA, NA,
              NA, "cat", NA, NA)

df %>%
  unite(newCol, col1, col2, col3, col4,
        remove = FALSE,
        sep = ', ') %>%
  # Replace NAs and "NA, "s with ''
  mutate(newCol = gsub('NA[, ]*', '', newCol)) %>%
  # Replace ', ' with '' if it is at the end of the line
  mutate(newCol = gsub(', $', '', newCol)) %>%
  # Add the parentheses on either side
  mutate(newCol = paste0('(', newCol, ')'))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>            newCol  col1  col2  col3  col4
#>             <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1      (dog, cat)   dog   cat  <NA>  <NA>
#> 2 (cat, foo, bar)  <NA>   cat   foo   bar
#> 3           (dog)   dog  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
#> 4           (cat)  <NA>   cat  <NA>  <NA>
```

Also for what it's worth, other people are [discussing this problem](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/203)!